# How can I call grunt prompt task from copy task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-prompt

I am using load-grunt-config and I have a simple copy task setup like this inside my Gruntfile.js,

```
grunt.registerTask('copy-css', 'Blah.', ['copy:css'])
```

And then inside my copy.js file I have this (ignore the invalid code. The copy task is working fine, I am just setting up this example).

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt, options) {
    if(!grunt.file.exists(foldername)) { 
        //I NEED TO RUN A PROMPT HERE BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING
        grunt.task.run('prompt:directory-exists');
    }

    return {
        'css': {
            'files': [{
            }]
        }
    };
};
```

My prompt task looks something like this,

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    'directory-exists': {
        'options': {
            'questions': [{
                'type': 'confirm',
                'message': 'That folder already exists. Are you sure you want to continue?',
                'choices': ['Yes (overwrite my project files)', 'No (do nothing)']
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Grunt is not finding this task though, which I think has to do with how I am calling it considering I am using load-grunt-config.

Comment: Which plugin defines the prompt task ? Could you post the complete Gruntfile.js please ?

Comment: @Eria Using load-grunt-config, I am calling tasks by 'nameoffile:task' such as prompt:directory-exists. I am calling a bunch of tasks in this way in my gruntfile, however doing it here does not seem to be working. Notice above that the filename is copy.js and the task is css (copy:css).

Comment: load-grunt-config allows you to put your config declarations in separate files. But it doesn't load tasks. What you posted as "my prompt task" is just the config object for a task. Where is defined the corresponding "prompt" task ?

Comment: @Eria That file is named prompt.js, so it was my expectation that I could call the task like I do all my other tasks (prompt:task).

Comment: I think you don't understand how load-grunt-config works. The file name doesn't define a task. The file name must be the same as an existing task, so load-grunt-config can generate the effective config object. For example, your copy.js file will contain a module which return the configuration for the 'copy' task, probably defined in the plugin https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy. So, there must be a 'prompt' task existing for which your prompt.js file returns the config.

Comment: @Eria Ah I see. Yes I am pretty new to grunt. However I am also using (load-grunt-tasks) which is loading all the grunt-* files from node_modules for me. That task is grunt-prompt so it should be working just like the other tasks.

Comment: I think the problem is you define actions in your copy.js file. But that's not the purpose of this file. It should provide load-grunt-config with the config of 'copy' task. I think you should create your own task ('copy-css' for example, but not only as an alias for several tasks) and call the 'prompt' task in it. Now if you need help with that, I think it could usefull you post your gruntfile.js and maybe a part of your project structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101700/discussion-between-metropolis-and-eria).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going about this differenlty. Instead of checking to see if the directory exists, I am just getting a list of the directories, passing that to the prompt question and forcing the user to choose a directory before it ever gets to the copy task.

```
//Get directories
var projects = grunt.file.expand({filter: "isDirectory", cwd: "project"}, ["*"]);

//Format these for grunt-prompt
grunt.option('global.project.list', projects.map(function (proj_name) { return { 'value': proj_name, 'name': proj_name}; }));

//Prompt.js
return {
    //Prompt the user to choose their directory
    'project-name': {
        'options': {
            'questions': [{
                config: 'my.selection', 
                type: 'list',
                message: 'Choose directory to copy to?', 
                choices: grunt.option('global.project.list')
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you register a task, you will have access to the tasks in grunt config (like prompt).

Here is an example of a task you can create in your Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.registerTask('myowntask', 'My precious, my own task...', function(){
    // init
    var runCopy = true;

    // You'll need to retrieve or define foldername somewhere before...
    if( grunt.file.exists( foldername )) {
        // If your file exists, you call the prompt task, with the specific 'directory-exists' configuration you put in your prompt.js file
        grunt.task.call('prompt:directory-exists');
    }

}
```

Then, you run `grunt myowntask`.